# Running out of memory when building features (converting images into derived features [numpy arrays])?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, tensorflow, feature-extraction

I copied some image data to an instance on Google Cloud (8 vCPU's, 64GB memory, Tesla K80 GPU) and am running into memory problems when converting the raw data into features, and changing the data structure of the output. Eventually I'd like to use the derived features in Keras/Tensorflow neural net.

**Process**

After copying the data to a storage bucket, I run a build_features.py function to convert the raw data into processed data for the neural network. In this pipeline, I first take each raw image and put it into a list x (which stores the derived features).

Since I'm working with a large number of images (tens of thousands of images that are type float32 and have dimensions 250x500x3) the list x becomes quite large. Each element of x is numpy array that stores the image in shape 250x500x3.

**Problem 1 - reduced memory as list x grows**

I took 2 screenshots that show available memory decreasing as x grows (below). I'm eventually able to complete this step but I'm only left with a few GB of memory so I definitely want to fix this (in the future I want to work with larger data sets). **How can I build features in a way where I'm not limited by the size of x?**

[image]
[image]

**Problem 2 - Memory error when converting x into numpy array**

The step where the instance actually fails is the following:

```
x = np.array(x)
```

The failure message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build_features.py", line 149, in <module>
    build_features(pipeline='9_11_2017_fan_3_lights')
  File "build_features.py", line 122, in build_features
    x = np.array(x)
MemoryError
```

**How can I adjust this step so that I don't run out of memory?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has two copies of every image - one in the list, and one in the array:

```
images = []
for i in range(many):
    images[i] = load_img(i) # here's the first image

x = np.array(images) # joint them all together into a second copy
```

Just load the images straight into the array

```
x = np.zeros((many, 250, 500, 3)
for i in range(many):
    x[i] = load_img(i)
```

Which means that you only hold a copy of one image at a time.

---

If you don't know the size or dtype of the image ahead of time, or don't want to hard code it, you can use:

```
x0 = load_img(0)
x = np.zeros((many,) + x0.shape, x0.dtype)
for i in range(1, many):
    x[i] = load_img(i)
```

---

Having said that, you're on a tricky path here. If you don't have enough room to store your dataset twice in memory, you also don't have room to compute `y = x + 1`.

You might want to consider using `np.float16` to buy more storage, at the cost of precision

Comment: But in my case the first list x and the numpy array x have the same name. So am I not overwriting the first array, thereby not storing 2 copies?

Comment: @megashigger: The list can only be destroyed after the array is created, so there's an overlap period when both exist. You're correct that if you manage to execute that line, the memory usage will drop back down again to roughly what it was